# Getting dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use GitLab CI to run my automated tests and need to run a few `docker exec` commands during the tests.

I am getting this error however:

```
error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/json": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

I was searching about it and found [this solution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/4794#note_402203029) but it's only for when you're hosting your own GitLab Runner - which we aren't so I can't seem to use this solution.

Here's my over-simplified `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: docker:23.0.3

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ''
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1
  CI_DEBUG_SERVICES: "true"

services:
  - name: registry.gitlab.com/path/to/image:tag
    alias: 'testserver'

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - echo '>>>>> DEBUG - install all required packages and project dependencies'
    - apk update && apk add nodejs npm git
    - npm install --global yarn
    - yarn install
  script:
    - echo '>>>>> DEBUG - list docker containers'
    - docker ps
    - echo '>>>>> DEBUG - run tests'
    - yarn test:ci
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
  coverage: '/All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/'
```

I added the `docker ps` to see the containers that are running but that also gives the same error:

```
error during connect: Get "http://docker:2375/v1.24/containers/json": dial tcp: lookup docker on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host
```

Comment: If you're not using your own runner, you don't need to set `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR` or `DOCKER_DRIVER` but you do need to add the `docker:dind` container to your `services:` -- see also: [the gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-no-such-host-error)

Comment: Thank you @sytech - using dind did fix the issue but now I have a different problem.